# reorder css table on browser resize

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to reorder a pure css table on browser resize, so that a table with one row and three cells becomes a table with three rows, one cell on each row?

The code I have is:

```
<div style="display:table; width:90%;">
  <div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:70%; height:500px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 1</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:5%; height:500px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 2</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:25%; height:500px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which gives a table with three side by side cells.

I want to create a media query so that under a certain browser width, this table would re-order to display something like this...

```
<div style="display:table; width:90%;">
  <div style="display:table-row;"><div style="display:table-cell; width:100%; height:500px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 1</div></div>
  <div style="display:table-row;"><div style="display:table-cell; width:100%; height:25px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 2</div></div>
  <div style="display:table-row;"><div style="display:table-cell; width:100%; height:250px; border:1px solid #333;">cell 3</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with media queries. You will need to manage widths here.

You can Expand snippet to see this working in Full Page.

```css
.rowLayout
{
 display:table-cell;
 height:500px;
 border:1px solid #333;
}

.width70{
 width:70%;
}

.width25{
 width:25%;
}

.width5{
 width:5%;
}

.rowDisplay{
display:table-row;
}

@media screen and  (max-width: 520px) 
{
.rowLayout
{
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.width70,.width25,.width5{
 width:100%;
}
.rowDisplay{
display:table;
}

}
```

```html
<div style="display:table; width:90%;">
  <div class="rowDisplay">
    <div class="rowLayout width70" >cell 1</div>
    <div class="rowLayout width5" >cell 2</div>
    <div class="rowLayout width25" >cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well. But changing the cells into blocks means that the table row has blocks within it, (Like <tr>content</tr> but no table cells (<td></td>). Is that acceptable?

Comment: This code does not render actual table row. It makes the component where this class is being applied act like a table row in its local scope. So, it will work fine in css. I have anyways put that in another css class now, and applied a fix.

Answer (score 1):

First you should apply class names to your DIV tags in the HTML (instead of inline styles), then you can assign the table properties to them via classes and change that in a media query, like in the example below: (Use fullscreen view and change the window width to see the effect)

```css
.container_1 {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
}

.x1 {
  display: table-row;
}

.x2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .x1 {
    display: block;
  }
  .x2 {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1">
  <div class="x1">
    <div class="x2">cell 1</div>
    <div class="x2">cell 2</div>
    <div class="x2">cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    table {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

You can read more about this at:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: All that will do is set the width of the table, not re-order the elements within the structure.